# Java Secure FTP Applet

Tags: java, ftp, applet, sftp

Does everyone know if there's an example of code of an application similar to these one?

http://www.jscape.com/sftpapplet/sftp_applet_demo.html

It's an applet that allows to upload huge files into an FTP Active server via HTTP using a Java Applet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a step by step:

1. Create a class which accepts a `File...` argument and sends them to a SFTP server. Any Java SSH API should suffice. Here are the open source ones:

   - [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)
   - [SSHTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshtools/)
   - [Another overview](http://linuxmafia.com/ssh/java.html)

   Test it as a simple Java Application with a `main()` method.
2. Create a nice [Swing UI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/) utilizing the functionality of the class you created at step 1. You can for example use a [JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to select local files for upload.
3. Create an [Applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) which launches the Swing UI which you created at step 2.
4. Embed the applet in a HTML page using `<applet>` or `<object>` tags or using the unversal applet deployment tool in flavor of [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html).

#### Related questions:

- [What is the best way to SFTP a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)
- [Java SFTP transfer library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346764/java-sftp-transfer-library)