# NullPointerException in Java script library

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, jsch

I am making a first step into Java- trying to create a simple Java script library in Domino Designer 8.5.2 to perform SFTP file transfers using JSch 0.1.48. The library will be called from a LotusScript agent via LS2J. Here is my SFTP class from the script library, based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690960/461954):

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

public class SFTP {
    public String GetFile(String host, String user, String pass, 
                          String localPath, String remotePath) {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(pass);
            session.connect();
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            sftpChannel.get(remotePath, localPath);
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = "OK";
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I call this function from a Java agent, it appears to work without any issues. When I call it from a LotusScript agent via LS2J, it transfers the file but then it throws error 318 - LS2J Error: Threw java.lang.NullPointerException. The Java stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkRelatedThreadGroup(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.checkAccess(Thread.java:378)
    at java.lang.Thread.interrupt(Thread.java:506)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.disconnect(Session.java:1630)
    at SFTP.GetFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at lotus.domino.JavaConnectInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at lotus.domino.JavaConnectLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The issue seems to be with the session.disconnect() call. I've found others [with](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=141609&ei=jf3pT9q5MKro2QW-4aThCA&usg=AFQjCNHDkqfP-uuTlmEZpJkQXJpTqtz-iQ&sig2=-vojJp1370z87iW5oFYlRg) [similar](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFUQFjAB&url=http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=509122&aid=1701750&group_id=64920&ei=jf3pT9q5MKro2QW-4aThCA&usg=AFQjCNHQy6pW8kk6IH35RIm1nl-JTTGRBw&sig2=y1YzcURAiDWNKjYBJK8omw) [issues](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFYQFjAC&url=https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=175328&ei=jf3pT9q5MKro2QW-4aThCA&usg=AFQjCNGDEaTWt1B-x19yjI8oXqJMcs2whg&sig2=PmJAxCYAV4DyXdJxbK3HZg&cad=rja) calling JSch from other applications, but if it's a JSch bug I would think the Java agent would throw the same exception. The stack trace makes it look like it's a Domino security issue, but I don't know what adjustment to make to allow this operation. The agent is already set to allow restricted operations, so that's not it. This [forum post](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/02d5579edc50a6d88525687b004b21e8?OpenDocument) has a similar stack trace and suggests that the issue may be caused by Domino owning cleanup rights on its thread group.

Is there a security change I need to make on the Domino side? Can I remove the session.disconnect() without orphaning a zillion connections on the server?

Comment: Please don't call them `Java Scripts` because it is very confusing with the scripting language, `Javascript` which is a completely different language.

Comment: A "script library" is a Domino design element- a non-executable library of code. A script library can contain either Java or LotusScript, hence the nomenclature "Java script library".

Comment: Then I would give the same advice to Domino to call it a code library rather than a script library, especially since Java is not a scripting language. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred in the AgentSecurityManager, which you can read about in [this blog entry](http://lekkimworld.com/2006/04/23/1145790357201.html).  It's basically a shim that the Domino AMGR inserts into the JVM to enforce Domino's security policies.

Check to make sure that you have granted the agent rights to use restricted operations.  (In another example of Lotus' oddball terminology, the signer must have rights in the "Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations" field of the server document, but agent must have rights granted on security tab of the agent properties box to "Allow restricted operations")

If it's not something simple like that, then I suggest you try taking the jar(s) for com.jcraft.jsch.* out of the Domino script library and putting them in the jvm/lib/ext folder on the server's filesystem.  Security for jars stored on the filesystem is handled different, and it might get around the problem.

Comment: We have java.policy wide open and the agent does have unrestricted rights...however, I can't reproduce the issue now. If it comes back, I'll try the /jvm/lib/ext suggestion and let you know. I also have another similar issue that I may post a new question for. Thanks for taking a look at this one.