# SFTP connection with FTPSClient is failing

Tags: java, sftp, ftp-client, ftps, apache-commons-net

Below code I'm trying to connect SFTP host using `FTPSClient`. Instead of FTP client, I'm using `FTPSClient` to connect. But I'm facing issue to connect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        String host ="sftphost.com";
        String user = "abc";
        String pwd  = "pwd"
        final FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();        
        System.out.println("host:"+host);
        ftp.connect(host,22);       
        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        ftp.login(user, pwd);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FTPS is not SFTP](https://superuser.com/q/677966/213663).

You cannot use Apache Commons Net FTPS client `FTPSClient` to connect to SFTP port 22. That's a completely different protocol.

You have to use a different library. The most commonly used SFTP library for Java is [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

See also [Secure FTP with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12803942/850848#27902150).