# Best way to send files via FTP inSpring boot

Tags: xml, spring-boot, ftp

I have a Kotlin SpringBoot project and I need to create an xml file and send it by FTP. What would be the best way / library to do this? Is it possible to send xml file without saving it first? I have been able to create a correct format xml, but sending is a bit tricky.

Answer (score -1):

I have used [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for FTP/SFTP transfers in the past. It allows you to send files and/or streams to a destination server. Using the later would prevent you from having to write out the XML before sending it.

Comment: JSch is an SFTP library, not FTP. A commonly used FTP library for Java is Apache Common Net. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12803942/850848#27902150

Comment: You are correct. I haven't dealt with insecure transfers in ages and assumed the transfer was to be secure.