# Can FTPSClient from Apache Java library be used to transfer a file over SFTP?

Tags: java, sftp

There is already a question on this:
[Secure FTP with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803942/secure-ftp-with-org-apache-commons-net-ftp-ftpclient)

But there is no accepted answer given.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Non-acceptance of answer doesn't mean the answers given are not useful. Try them and see if any of them work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure FTP with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803942/secure-ftp-with-org-apache-commons-net-ftp-ftpclient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you understand a difference between FTPS (Secure FTP) and SFTP:
[FTPS versus SFTP versus SCP](https://superuser.com/q/677966/213663)

If you need FTPS (Secure FTP), follow advices given in the question you pointed to yourself:
[Secure FTP with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12803942/850848)

If you need SFTP, see:
[How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14617/850848)
[Java SFTP Transfer Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346764/850848)