# Problems with connecting with it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient to SFTP

Tags: java, sftp, ftp-client, ftp4j

I am having problems connecting with `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient`.

I want to use SFTP but always get errors.

- If I use:

  ```
  sftpClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES)
  ```

  I get:
  `ERROR c.l.datamanager.Ftp4jFTPTask - it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException ERROR c.l.datamanager.Ftp4jFTPTask - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not connected`
- If I use

  ```
  sftpClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPS);
  ```

  I get:
  `ERROR c.l.datamanager.Ftp4jFTPTask - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message c.l.datamanager.Ftp4jFTPTask - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not connected`

Please let me know how I can use SFTP in `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient`.

Answer (score 1):

FTPES is not SFTP. You cannot use FTP(E(S)) library to connect to an SFTP server. FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols.

You have to use an SFTP library. See [Java SFTP Transfer Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346764/850848)