# Java : Downloading file from a remote location using sftp

Tags: java, ftp, download, sftp, apache-camel

I have to  download a file which is in remote location using SFTP on clicking a hyperlink  . Am using JBOSS 5.1 as my Server and using struts2. I have implemented the below code and i found out the receiveBody() of the ConsumerTemplate is coming as null ?
Can any one please guide me to the above issue ?

Code :

```
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
                ConsumerTemplate consumer = ctx.createConsumerTemplate();
                String camel_ftp_uri = MessageFormat.format(CAMEL_FTP_PATTERN, ftp_mode, ftp_user, ftp_address, ftp_dir, ftp_options);
                System.out.println("camel_ftp_uri ::: "+camel_ftp_uri);

                Object obj= consumer.receiveBody(camel_ftp_uri);
                System.out.println("obj  ::"+obj);
```

when am printing the `camel_ftp_uri` am getting :camel_ftp_uri :::

`ftp://ccc_uat1@1x.xxx.xx.xxx//from_ccc/file.txt?disconnect=true`

I refered the below link in SOF :

[How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a "do my work for me" request.  What have you already tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: @Omaha Thank you for your kind consideration . I have clearly mentioned am new to SFTP and am not getting what they mentioned in the link given

Comment: Have a read of http://serverfault.com/questions/176149/how-to-provide-a-web-interface-to-sftp-server and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

The Camel FTP component you have to configure the ftp uri with a starting directory, and then provide the file name to download as a seperate parameter. What you do wrong is that the starting directory is the file name.

This

```
ftp://ccc_uat1@1x.xxx.xx.xxx//from_ccc/file.txt?disconnect=true
```

Should be changed to

```
ftp://ccc_uat1@1x.xxx.xx.xxx//from_ccc/?disconnect=true&fileName=file.txt
```