# how to upload a Folder from Windows to Linux machine using Java

Tags: java

how to upload a Folder from Windows to Linux machine using Java. Windows machine is the client machine. I am establishing the connection to Linux machine on windows machine using putty, java code will be running on linux machine. This is a servlet based project.

Comment: Wait, uploading means pushing content from a client to a server.  Yet you have stated that the Java app is on the server.  You've also thrown a Putty connection into the equation, rather than using any number of known file transfer protocols.  This question is quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying FTP, since your working from Linux to Windows.

Windows is a little cranky about these things so it might take some setting up it get it to work.

Check out [How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server) for some suggestions.

If you can, I'd reverse the process, copy the folder from Windows to Linux, Linux just seems to be easier to get setup to handle this kind of thing...IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTP, SSH or Telnet. FTP and SSH are preferable. 
If you choose SSH I suggest you to use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). For FTP you can use [VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) from Jakarta.