# Shared data cloud storage for Android

Tags: android, api, sdk, cloud

I'm developing android application that needs to store and read data from some shared storage in the cloud.

I'm wondering is there is already existing android API/SDK for pushing and getting data from some abstract "cloud storage" or will I have to implement and host my own server?

Answer (score 0):

A. Look briefly into [Amazon AWS SDK for Android](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/), while I dont say you just *must* use it.

B. If just to store the data, another trivial solution could be to use SFTP server, with some [SFTP java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server) on Android side. SFTP server is trivial to setup (with OpenSSH) and some providers (like [Nine](http://nine.ch/managed-vserver/plans), for instance) are also ready to maintain and backup it for you.