# Upload file to remote folder from local folder using SFTP

Tags: java, file-upload, sftp

Am trying to upload file to remote folder from local folder.But am getting an error, I don't know where I made a mistake. I hope someone helps to find the solution. Thanks.

The code given below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "www.xyz.com";
        int port = 22;
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "admin@12";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            System.out.println("1");
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            System.out.println("2");
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            System.out.println("3");

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            System.out.println("4");

            // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
            File firstLocalFile = new File("D:/UploadServlet.java");

            String firstRemoteFile = "Projects.zip";
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

            System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            if (done) {
                System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
            }



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I execute the code am getting the below error.

```
Error: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:284)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:335)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:550)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:163)
    at FTPUploadFileDemo.main(FTPUploadFileDemo.java:26)
org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: Protocol mismatch.
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:284)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:460)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:520)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:569)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.quit(FTP.java:781)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.logout(FTPClient.java:706)
    at FTPUploadFileDemo.main(FTPUploadFileDemo.java:58)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621325/ftpsclient-returns-malformedserverreplyexception-cannot-parse-response-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server

Comment: Wrong port? `22` is default for SSH. You are using FTP which is default on port `21`. Do you want to use SFTP (FTP over SSH) or FTPS (FTP over SSL)?

Comment: @SubOptimal am trying to upload FTP over SSH

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you use valid ftp server and port?

```
String server = "www.xyz.com";
int port = 22;
```

Server from your example return "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1"

```
telnet www.xyz.com 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
```

Comment: yes. www.xyz.com is just an example and its correct oly

Comment: I think FTPClient wouldn't work with FTP over SSH, more details and advices in duplicate comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621325/ftpsclient-returns-malformedserverreplyexception-cannot-parse-response-code

Comment: http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-uploading-file-to-sftp-server/ - one more useful link

Answer (score 0):

For SFTP (FTP over SSH) you cannot use the library [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/), as it supports FTPS (FTP over SSL).

But you could use for example [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) a pure Java implementation of SSH2 (BSD style license) or any commercial SFTP library.

An SFTP example for Jsch is provided at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.

Answer (score 0):

The below SFTP Utility gives an example of Upload, Exist, Download, Move and Delete operations. I have used this in several of my projects. The below code uses api calls from Apache Commons VFS library only.

Please make sure that you put the following JAR's in your project's build path:

1. commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
2. commons-vfs2-2.0.jar
3. hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
4. jsch-0.1.50.jar

Any other compatible versions would do as well.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.Selectors;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder;

/**
 * The class SFTPUtil containing uploading, downloading, checking if file exists
 * and deleting functionality using Apache Commons VFS (Virtual File System)
 * Library
 * 
 * @author Ashok
 * 
 */
public class SFTPUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostName = "PutYourHostNameHere";
        String username = "PutYourUserNameForHostHere";
        String password = "PutYourPasswordForHostHere";

        String localFilePath = "C:\\FakePath\\FakeFile.txt";
        String remoteFilePath = "/FakeRemotePath/FakeRemoteFile.txt";       
        String remoteTempFilePath = "/FakeRemoteTempPath/FakeRemoteTempFile.txt";

        upload(hostName, username, password, localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
        exist(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath);
        download(hostName, username, password, localFilePath,remoteFilePath);
        move(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath, remoteTempFilePath);
        delete(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath);
    }

    /**
     * Method to upload a file in Remote server
     * 
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param localFilePath
     *            LocalFilePath. Should contain the entire local file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with \\ as separator
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     */
    public static void upload(String hostName, String username, String password, String localFilePath, String remoteFilePath) {

        File file = new File(localFilePath);
        if (!file.exists())
            throw new RuntimeException("Error. Local file not found");

        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create local file object
            FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            // Create remote file object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());
            /*
             * use createDefaultOptions() in place of fsOptions for all default
             * options - Ashok.
             */

            // Copy local file to sftp server
            remoteFile.copyFrom(localFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);

            System.out.println("File upload success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    public static boolean move(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteSrcFilePath, String remoteDestFilePath){
        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create remote object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteSrcFilePath), createDefaultOptions());
            FileObject remoteDestFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteDestFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            if (remoteFile.exists()) {
                remoteFile.moveTo(remoteDestFile);;
                System.out.println("Move remote file success");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Source file doesn't exist");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to download the file from remote server location
     * 
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param localFilePath
     *            LocalFilePath. Should contain the entire local file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with \\ as separator
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     */
    public static void download(String hostName, String username, String password, String localFilePath, String remoteFilePath) {

        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Append _downlaod_from_sftp to the given file name.
            //String downloadFilePath = localFilePath.substring(0, localFilePath.lastIndexOf(".")) + "_downlaod_from_sftp" + localFilePath.substring(localFilePath.lastIndexOf("."), localFilePath.length());

            // Create local file object. Change location if necessary for new downloadFilePath
            FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(localFilePath);

            // Create remote file object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            // Copy local file to sftp server
            localFile.copyFrom(remoteFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);

            System.out.println("File download success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to delete the specified file from the remote system
     * 
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param localFilePath
     *            LocalFilePath. Should contain the entire local file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with \\ as separator
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     */
    public static void delete(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create remote object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            if (remoteFile.exists()) {
                remoteFile.delete();
                System.out.println("Delete remote file success");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    // Check remote file is exist function:
    /**
     * Method to check if the remote file exists in the specified remote
     * location
     * 
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     * @return Returns if the file exists in the specified remote location
     */
    public static boolean exist(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

        try {
            manager.init();

            // Create remote object
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(hostName, username, password, remoteFilePath), createDefaultOptions());

            System.out.println("File exist: " + remoteFile.exists());

            return remoteFile.exists();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates SFTP URL connection String
     * 
     * @param hostName
     *            HostName of the server
     * @param username
     *            UserName to login
     * @param password
     *            Password to login
     * @param remoteFilePath
     *            remoteFilePath. Should contain the entire remote file path -
     *            Directory and Filename with / as separator
     * @return concatenated SFTP URL string
     */
    public static String createConnectionString(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
        return "sftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + hostName + "/" + remoteFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * Method to setup default SFTP config
     * 
     * @return the FileSystemOptions object containing the specified
     *         configuration options
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public static FileSystemOptions createDefaultOptions() throws FileSystemException {
        // Create SFTP options
        FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

        // SSH Key checking
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");

        /*
         * Using the following line will cause VFS to choose File System's Root
         * as VFS's root. If I wanted to use User's home as VFS's root then set
         * 2nd method parameter to "true"
         */
        // Root directory set to user home
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);

        // Timeout is count by Milliseconds
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);

        return opts;
    }
}
```