# Upload file FTP server

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, apache-commons-net

I am stuck during connecting to my FTP server through apache FTP client. I found lots of program out there but I am not able to connect to my FTP server through the below code.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect("169.144.76.33");
ftpClient.login("root", "re123set");
```

Exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:176)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:268)
```

But whenever I am trying to connect through FileZilla with IP, user name, password, port (without port can't connect). I am getting able to connect to the FTP server.

So please help me to resolve the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact you need to enter a port in FileZilla (which defaults to the FTP port `21`), I assume, you are not providing some information to the `FTPClient`:

1. Port number (assuming it's different from the default `21`). To connect to a non-default port, use the `Connect` overload with two arguments:

   ```
   public void connect(String hostname, int port)
   ```
2. You may be using an implicit SSL/TLS encryption, what FileZilla (but not the `FTPClient`) could assume from a port number `990`
3. You actually want to use the SFTP (based on the `sftp` tag with your question). The `FTPClient` does not support the SFTP protocol, it's totally distinct from the FTP. See [How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14617/850848)