# Convert from FTP to SFTP

Tags: java

I have the below code which works for FTP. How do I make it to work for SFTP

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(cmd);
channel.setXForwarding(true);
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();
return in;
```

I know that I need to use ChannelSftp instead of Channel class, but I get type cast error in the setcommand line.
Cannot cast type ChannelSftp to ChannelExec

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server

Comment: What is that command? Is it an FTP command you are trying to use with SFTP? (sorry, don't know that lib)

Comment: cmd will be passed on as a parameter. It could be "top" for example

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is SFTP is different than FTP or FTP/s. SFTP works off of SSH whereas FTP/s uses SSL.

That being said, JSCH provides a pretty straight forward way to use SFTP, including setting X forwarding. Take a look at the [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) as well as the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server) from mabbas.

Based upon your comment, it appears that you actually want a remote shell to be invoked/executed against, try the following to see if it'll do what you need:

```
//connect to the remote shell
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
((ChannelShell)channel).setAgentForwarding(true);
channel.setInputStream(System.in); //Send commands here
channel.setOutputStream(System.out); //output responses here      
channel.connect();
```

You won't be able to use `ChannelSftp` as it does not have a `setCommand` or `exec` method

Comment: What is the difference between this code and the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSCH, they have [several example programs](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) which illustrate how to use the library. [The SFTP client example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) illustrates how to open an SFTP session.

```
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
...
session.connect();

Channel channel=session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp c=(ChannelSftp)channel;
```

That's all you have to do. `ChannelSftp` contains functions to send and receive files, get file listings, and so on. You don't have to access the channel's input or output streams.