# Secure-FTP or FTP-S for android using Cordova 2.9.0

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sftp, cordova-plugins

I want to upload files on an Android app using Secure-FTP or FTP-S. I am able to upload files using a ftp client, available on github(Link: https://github.com/macdonst/FtpClient/tree/master/v2.2.0).

I would like to know how to go about implementing Secure-FTP or FTP-S. I have researched a lot on this but did not find sufficient documentation. So it would be great if anyone could provide me with suggestions or any helpful links in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used Java SFTP client library is Jsch.

See this answer for details:

[How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)

It works fine on Android.

Comment: I am new to android development. The code is basically in java. How do I refer it using phonegap?

Comment: Unfortunately there does not seem to be a Jsch/SFTP plugin for PhoneGap/Cordova at this time. You would need to write it yourself or have someone write it for you.

Comment: is there any helpful documentation you know of that could help me in this case.. That would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the party ... however, i wrote a sftp plugin for cordova only for android that works. This plugin uses JSCh as sftp client.

It can be installed using :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/sdkcarlos/cordova-ourcodeworld-sftpplugin.git
```

The plugin offers support for the following tasks :

- Secure connection
- List a remote path
- Upload files
- Download files
- Delete remote file
- Use private key to connect
- Download/Upload progress indicator

[Read the information of the plugin here](https://sdkcarlos.github.io/sites/cordova/sftp-plugin.html).