# Writing Java code to do secure ftp

Tags: java, ftp

I have a Java app that queries a file database. Depending on the query, I get a set of results (files) ranked in a certain order. I got this to work locally, and the user can open those files by double-clicking on the results, one by one. Now, I am moving everything to an external server, and I have the Java program query the database on the server. I get the same results back. Now, the files are also stored on the server, they are not local, so, when the user double-clicks, I need to do some secure ftp (or something similar, I can take suggestions) to copy the file and open it locally (and, if desired, save it).
This is the problem, I have no idea where to start, is there a good Java library I should use, look at, in order to accomplish this? Username and password for the ftp can be hard-coded if necessary, should this make things any easier (though it's probably the same). FYI the files are mostly pdf, html, word or text, not binary. Thanks!

Comment: There are a few, [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) comes to mind

Comment: FYI: pdf & word are considered binary.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I am looking at them. Sorry if this was off-topic, I will be looking at the suggestions and post a better question if I get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your business requirements and constraints, but you can look at the [Dropbox API for Java](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java).  This could be either a slick suggestion or a terrible one depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As @MadProgrammer suggested [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Refer to following post already answering your concern :

> [java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)