# How do I check my program for updates in Java

Tags: java, swing, deployment, updates, auto-update

I am wondering how I can make my Java game automatically check for updates when a button is pressed, I have an `ActionListener` calling my `UpdateGUI` class:

```
btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new UpdateGUI();
    }
});
```

and then I am stuck from here  on, I've got the GUI sorted (labels, buttons etc), but it's just the update checker, I also would like help to make a label appear when an update is available.

I have tried looking through the various questions provided to me as I was making this question, all of which did not help me.

UpdateGUI Code

```
public class UpdateGUI {

    public UpdateGUI() {
        JFrame starGameUpdater = new JFrame();
        starGameUpdater.setTitle("StarGame Updater");
        starGameUpdater.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel labelStargameUpdate = new JLabel("StarGame Updater");
        labelStargameUpdate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        labelStargameUpdate.setBounds(165, 11, 94, 14);
        starGameUpdater.getContentPane().add(labelStargameUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of update? New data, new Java version or new application version? You'll may need a component that can send an HTTP-Request to the corresponding server that will deliver newest version number.

Comment: When I release a new version of my game onto my FTP server

Comment: Please check this question, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server.

Comment: That sort of helped me, I need to check for a newly modified version of the game, and then download it and replace the .jar file it (downloads from the launcher and executed the new .jar file)

Comment: or, exit after it installs the new update and drops the file i... say like folder in %appdata% (in StarGame folder (name of my game)) or Desktop in a new folder

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can go about doing this @Tom

Comment: No, but I guess there are a lot of questions/tutorials available on how to request files from an ftp server.

Comment: Use [tag:java-web-start].

Comment: Me personally I would copy how it is done for Minecraft: using an external launcher application which can update and manage the game rather than a Java program which updates itself. Check for update, download, start new Java process (using Process class) to actually boot the game. That also gives you the flexibility to provide startup parameters to the forked process.

Comment: @Gimby and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I've just looked through the whole minecraft code, I cannot find anything to do with updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) provides auto-updates.  The JNLP API available to JWS apps. also allows the app. to take programmatic control of updates through the [`DownloadService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html).

> `DownloadService` service allows an application to control how its own resources are cached, to determine which of its resources are currently cached, to force resources to be cached, and to remove resources from the cache. The JNLP Client is responsible for providing a specific implementation of this service.