# how to connect to winscp with username and ppk file from java program

Tags: java, sftp, winscp

I have to generate and put some files on `WinSCP` using java program. For connecting to box (with `WinSCP`), I use following credentials:
host name:
username:
port:
private key file:

I searched through  [How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server) and found below code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
public class TestJSch 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;`enter code here`
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("username", "127.0.0.1", 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword("password");
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            sftpChannel.get("remotefile.txt", "localfile.txt");
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

All these codes are using password whereas I don't have password but a private key file.Can anybody help me to know how can I connect to server using a private key file only?

Comment: Note that you *do not connect to WinSCP*. WinSCP is an SFTP client that you use *to connect to SFTP server*.

Comment: jsch.addIdentity("path/for/private/key"); this worked for me..Thanks!