# "FtpProtocolException: Welcome message ..." when connecting to Ubuntu Server using Java

Tags: java, ftp

```
String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s;type=i";    
String host = "10.88.195.43:22";    
String user = "ionadmin";    
String pass = "ionadmin";    
String filePath = "D:\\JARS\\beforeRunSanity.txt";    
String uploadPath = "/home/ionadmin/";    
ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl, user, pass, host, uploadPath);    
System.out.println("Upload URL: " + ftpUrl);    
try {    
    URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);    
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();    
    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();    
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);    
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];    
    int bytesRead = -1;    
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {    
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);    
    }    
    inputStream.close();    
    outputStream.close();    
    System.out.println("File uploaded");    
} catch (IOException ex) {    
    ex.printStackTrace();    
}
```

I have provided all the valid credentials but I am Getting Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException:     sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: Welcome message: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1    
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)    
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown     Source)
```

If I remove the port number, its shows me ftpConnection Exception: invalid username/password

Comment: Port 22 seems to be wrong as default FTP port is 21

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting to SSH/SFTP port 22 using FTP protocol.

That cannot work.

- If you want to use the FTP, connect to the standard FTP port 21.
- If you actually wanted to use the SFTP, use an SFTP client.
  See [How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14617/850848).

Comment: Thank you !! Martin ... example given in above link  Java: What is the best way to SFTP a file from a server    worked for me.