# Unable to import the classes inspite of adding Pom dependency for Jcraft Jsch

Tags: java, sftp, pom.xml

I am posting this after spending significant amount of time reasearching about JAVA libraries to help SFTP a file. And I have read across couple of posts as well. Looking at the code samples in this post-
[How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)

I found the Jcraft jar for which I had to create a dependency in my pom, but inspite of that I am not able to see the import classes like Jsch , ChannelSFTP. Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: Can you add the Jsch dependency you added to your POM ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.53</version>
</dependency>
```

If you still don't see paste your pom file here.. There must be some issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

What I was *doing wrong*:
I was adding the dependency under the 
`<dependencyManagement>` tag.

What I did and it **fixed the problem**:
I added the dependency under the `<dependencies>` tag.