# How to connect to sftp server and read the contents of the file using java?

Tags: java

How to connect to sftp server and read the contents of the file using java?I have tried wring the code but I was not able to get the output,I did research a lot of things as to how to connect to sftp server by giving username,host and password.but didnt help

Comment: 1) write code 2) execute code 3) debug code. we'll maybe help with #3. #1-2 are your responsibility.

Comment: It seems that there is a similar question about that.
Check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)

Comment: Oh god @PrashanthEdige wrong place

Comment: A very detailed description in this posting [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)

Comment: Thanks@AlexanderPetrov