# Is there any Java API to transfer files from one server to another?

Tags: java, file-transfer

In my current Java application, I am using Linux commands to make copies of files that are locally stored on a server.

Now, I want to know how to transfer files from one server to another server, using a Java API.

Can anyone offer me some directions? Thank you.

Comment: Using which protocol? You can do that via ssh, ftp, http, etc. And for all those there are Java APIs.

Comment: like Files.copy?

Comment: Seems to have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/how-to-retrieve-a-file-from-a-server-via-sftp

Comment: Thanku @toongeorges This helped me

Answer (score -1):

You could invoke the exact same Linux commands via [Runtime.exec(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))