# FTP and SFTP file download library for Java

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

I would like some help in choosing the best library to use in order to download files from FTP and SFTP servers as bytes. I dont want to use separate libraries for FTP and SFTP and it should has the best performance. I made some research and found that Apache Camel may be the best among all, with Spring integration as competitor. 
The idea is to replace random libraries each for a different protocol and performance with a single one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/how-to-retrieve-a-file-from-a-server-via-sftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further analysis:

- From Apache Camel documentation: This component uses two different libraries for the actual FTP work. FTP and FTPS uses Apache Commons Net while SFTP uses JCraft JSCH.
- From Spring integration documentation: SFTP Session Factory relies on the JSch library to provide the SFTP capabilities. 
  And DefaultFtpSessionFactory provides an abstraction over the underlying client API which, since Spring Integration 2.0, is Apache Commons Net.

Which means that despite providing single interface for both protocols, the above two libraries don't have any advantage over apache net and JSCH